# It is so clear for what am I

Tags: riddle

> I am common, but special
>
> I am everywhere
>
> What special is, I expand when cooled
>
> Shrink when heated
>
> You will need me or you will die

Isn't it clear now what am I?

Comment: I'd have maybe said "all around you" or something rather than "everywhere"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Water

I am common, but special
I am everywhere

> on Earth there is a lot of water so it's common
>  But it is special because it facilitates life

What special is, I expand when cooled
Shrink when heated

> The density of ice is smaller than the density of liquid water

You will need me or you will die

> Try going a few weeks without water.

Answer (score 1):

You are water

I am everywhere

> In the air H20

What special is, I expand when cooled

> Ice

Shrink when heated

> evaporate

You will need me or you will die

> H20

Answer (score 1):

you are

> water

I am common, but special

> very common but required for life.

I am everywhere

> Water is every where

What special is, I expand when cooled
Shrink when heated

> Ice take more space than liquid water. Usually the solid takes less space.

You will need me or you will die

> without water you die.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to spice things up, and provide a new answer:

> Acetic acid ([main source here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid#Production) )

I am common, but special

> More commonly known as vinegar perhaps (acetic acid is one of the constituents). "The global demand for acetic acid is about 6.5 million metric tons per year (Mt/a), of which approximately 1.5 Mt/a is met by recycling; the remainder is manufactured from petrochemical feedstock." So quite common.

I am everywhere

> Acetic acid is produced industrially both synthetically and by bacterial fermentation. About 75% of acetic acid made for use in the chemical industry is made by the carbonylation of methanol, explained below.The biological route accounts for only about 10% of world production, but it remains important for the production of vinegar because many food purity laws require vinegar used in foods to be of biological origin.

What special is, I expand when cooled

Shrink when heated

> Acetic acid also has the property of having a lower density when cooled.

You will need me or you will die

> Perhaps not as evident as water, but "in biochemistry, the acetyl group, derived from acetic acid, is fundamental to all forms of life. When bound to coenzyme A, it is central to the metabolism of carbohydrates and fats."

Comment: Nice.  Educational.  If I were you I'd have made some tweaks and made my own riddle from this stuff.  Could have been a harder, science heavy, less broad version.  I'd never have gotten it if you did though haha.

Answer (score -1):

> water at a temperature between 0 and 4 degree celsius..